# fl_chart want to add last one week dates in bottomTitles in lineChart

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, linechart, fl-chart

**ERROR**:- **The return type 'String' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context.**
I need to add the last one-week date in the bottom titles but got an error in the updated version. in the previous version, it's working fine. but now I got this error when ugrade the flutter pub YAML.

[image]

```
   SideTitles get bottomTitles {
        return SideTitles(
        showTitles: true,
        getTitlesWidget: (value, meta) {
          String text = '';
          switch (value.toInt()) {
            case 1:
              return DateFormat('dd')
                  .format(DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 6)));
            case 2:
              return DateFormat('dd')
                  .format(DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 5)));
            case 3:
              return DateFormat('dd')
                  .format(DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 4)));
            case 4:
              return DateFormat('dd')
                  .format(DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 3)));
            case 5:
              return DateFormat('dd')
                  .format(DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 2)));
            case 6:
              return DateFormat('dd')
                  .format(DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 1)));
            case 7:
              return DateFormat('dd').format(DateTime.now());
          }
          return '';
        },
      );
      }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap them in `Text`, like

```
return Text(DateFormat('dd')
              .format(DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 6))));
```

It's always a good idea to check the changelog whenever you update a package. See https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart/changelog

Especially the BREAKING changes. The issue you are having is because of the changes in 0.50.0